# What is an order of transitions in state diagram? How to use history pseudo-states?

Tags: uml, state, diagrams

I read a lot about it, but still not sure in what order states executes (in Composite States) and how exactly deep and shallow history works? Could anybody help me?
I have an example, which I'm not sure how to solve, here it is:
[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It would be better if you specify further what exactly you do and do not understand and *what have you tried to figure out the solution*. If your question is too broad (which it currently is), it will likely be closed.

Comment: It's one of last year exams' questions. So first of all I'm not sure if I always should start from initial point, which is outside of all composites? I think so, but if first event is e1, then maybe I should start with this one which is inside? 2)IF I would start with this initial point on the left then before going inside of B state I should already execute "entry/x=x*2" operation? 3) As I believe when I leave state Y, my x should have a value of 7, but where should I go when I meet H..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Question 1:*

> ... not sure  .. how exactly deep and shallow history works?

*Answer 1:*

Note this:

> **A shallow history** is indicated by a small circle containing an "H". It applies to the state region that directly encloses it.
>
> Shallow history pseudostate represents the most recent active substate of its containing state (but not the substates of that substate). ...
>
> Source: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#shallow-history-pseudostate

*Question 2:*

> ... I'm not sure if I always should start from initial point, which is outside of all composites?

*Answer 2:*

Yes. You start from the Initial Pseudostate of the root state (A in this case).

*Example:*

For the given state-chart and event chain, you would get the following result (simulated with Rhapsody):

**after default transition to A**

- value of x (transition to A): `x = 3`
- value of x (entry A): `x = x * 2 = 6`
- new state: A

**after default transition to A::B**

- new state: A::B
- value of x: `x = 6`

[image]

**after e1**

- value of x (entry A::C): `x = x + 1 = 7`
- new state: A::C

**after default transition to A::C::G**

- value of x (entry A::C::G): `x = x + 1 = 8`
- new state: A::C::G

[image]

**after e3**

- value of x (exit A::C::G): `x = x - 2 = 6`
- value of x (entry A::C::H): `x = x / 2 = 3`
- new state: A::C::H

[image]

**after e4**

- value of x (entry A::C::G): `x = x + 1 = 4`
- new state: A::C::G

[image]

**after e6**

- value of x (exit A::C::G): `x = x - 2 = 2`
- value of x (exit A::C): `x = x - 1 = 1`
- value of x (exit A): `x = x - 1 = 0`
- value of x (transition to Y): `x = (x * 4) + 2 = 2`
- new state: Y

[image]

**after e7**

- value of x (**entry A::C** *see the note above*): `x = x + 1 = 3`
- value of x (entry A::C::G): `x = x + 1 = 4`
- new state: A::C::G

[image]

**e4 is discarded**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after e7

value of x (exit Y): `x = x / 2 = 1`

value of x (entry A): `x = x * 2 = 2`

value of x (entry A::C see the note above): `x = x + 1 = 3`

value of x (entry A::C::G): `x = x + 1 = 4`

new state: A::C::G